# 2 Camel routes consume same Queue

Tags: apache-camel, activemq-artemis

I've created multicast Address FROM.TEXT and an Anycast Queue FROM.TEXT inside this address. Configured this queue to have max-consumers="10".

```
    <address name="FROM.TEXT">
        <multicast>
            <queue name="FROM.TEXT" max-consumers="10">
                <durable>true</durable>
            </queue>
        </multicast>
    </address>
```

I created to 2 Camel routes that will consume messages from this queue and route to 2 different queue:

```
public void configure() throws Exception {

    InitialContext context = new InitialContext();

    from("jms:FROM.TEXT")
    .routeId("route1")
    .autoStartup(true)
    .convertBodyTo(String.class, "UTF-8")
    .to("jms:QUEUE1");

    getContext().start();

}
```

When I started the route1, its work, create a consumer for the queue, but when I start the route2, nothing happens. I need to this because the same message has to route to 2 different queues.

Thanks.

Comment: It doesn't make sense to say you've created a multicast address with an anycast queue.  What you've done is create an address with a single multicast queue.  However, since there is only 1 multicast queue the semantics will be no different from having a single anycast queue.  The point of multicast is that all the multicast queues will get any message sent to the address.  The point of anycast is that *1* of the anycast queues will get any message sent to the address.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want any client connected to the destination to get the same message then you should use a JMS topic. Just define an address supporting multicast:

```
<address name="FROM.TEXT">
    <multicast/>
</address>
```

Then you're route would be something like:

```
public void configure() throws Exception {
   InitialContext context = new InitialContext();

   from("jms:topic:FROM.TEXT")
   .routeId("route1")
   .autoStartup(true)
   .convertBodyTo(String.class, "UTF-8")
   .to("jms:queue:QUEUE1");

   getContext().start();
}
```

You'd define your `to` queue like this:

```
<address name="QUEUE1">
   <anycast>
      <queue name="QUEUE1">
   </anycast>
</address>
```

Comment: Thanks for you answer. So to create a Topic in Artemis, I need just create a Address with multicast tag and don't create a Queue? I'm sorry, but I really don't understand how Topic works on Artemis version.

Comment: Yes. To create a JMS topic in Artemis just create an `address` supporting `multicast`. There don't need to be any queues as the queues will be created by the broker automatically when subscribers connect. Then any message sent to the address will be placed in all the queues for all the subscribers. This information is noted in [the documentation](https://activemq.apache.org/artemis/docs/latest/jms-core-mapping.html).